# Using webview instead of native apps

Tags: android, ios, angular, webview

When you have to implement system which needs:

Backend, Frontend (Angular for instance), Android, IOS

**You are considering implementing a mobile version of frontend and use webview instead of native Android or IOS app?**

Of course, it depends on the project, but let assume:

- We don't have to use Android / IOS features like notifications, sensors (Bluetooth, nfc, ...)
- Our project is a page for instance "StackOverflow", where the user may authorize herself
- Nowadays, we are also implementing the mobile version of the frontend as a good habit

Usually, native apps would always be better, but maybe **it's faster and enough to use webview instead of implementing two native apps?**

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct answer to this. One could use a PWA, a hybrid app (many ways of doing that). As always, it depends. I don't even know if native apps are always better. They are more expensive in many cases, but if that is 'better'? Wouldn't a web app work too? It almost certainly is faster and cheaper to develop one (web-)app for multiple platforms, but what way to go is the best in your case is entirely up to you to decide.